# GNOME3 brightness slider for multiple desktop monitors

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, brightness, backlight

The GNOME3 brightness slider only works for one of the desktop monitors. A peek into kernel log reveals that it indeed only sends command to one monitor, via `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper /sys/devices/blah_blah`.

Is there a way to fix this slider to control multiple monitors simultaneously(or even better, have multiple sliders), instead of switching to other GNOME extensions?

BTW, I can confirm that `/sys/class/backlight` folder contains device folders that map all of the mointors. And I can manually `echo` to each `brightness` file to adjust individual monitors without a problem.

Comment: Eyesome in GitHub controls three monitors for brightness and Redshift like nighttime colors.

Comment: You can find [Eyesome here at GitHub](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome).